# Can a person die from over exposure to rain?

Tags: human-biology

Is it possible to die from being over exposed to rain? For example, if outside for a long amount of time (days) in a continuous storm?

I searched online but didn't find anything immediately. To me, maybe a really long exposure to rain (water) would cause skin tissue issues, which might then have potentially more serious effects on other body organs/systems.

Comment: Now that I think about it.... maybe I didn't find anything because it's never happened before... maybe I'm just not good at searching online. but still, can someone answer this question for me,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rain per se? No. But when you are wet, your body looses heat more quickly. If it's near freezing, windy, and raining you are in much more danger of developing [hypothermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothermia), or low body temperature. If your body temperature falls low enough, you can die. You may hear references to death from exposure, which is shorthand for "exposure to the elements", but the actual problem is hypothermia. If your feet are continuously wet for days and day, you may develop [immersion foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_foot_syndromes), also called trench foot:

> Trench foot is a medical condition caused by prolonged exposure of the
>   feet to damp, unsanitary, and cold conditions. The use of the word
>   trench in the name of this condition is a reference to trench warfare,
>   mainly associated with World War I. Affected feet may become numb,
>   affected by erythrosis (turning red) or cyanosis (turning blue) as a
>   result of poor vascular supply, and feet may begin to have a decaying
>   odour due to the possibility of the early stages of necrosis setting
>   in. As the condition worsens, feet may also begin to swell. Advanced
>   trench foot often involves blisters and open sores, which lead to
>   fungal infections; this is sometimes called tropical ulcer (jungle
>   rot).